# What can I eat to get more protein at breakfast time?

Tags: food, protein, breakfast

I'm looking for some different breakfast items that have more protein so I can stay full longer until closer to lunchtime. My typical breakfast includes some kind of cereal (a whole grain type, not a sugary kind) plus almond milk (regular milk upsets my stomach, and I dislike American soy milk). I'm not a huge fan of baked goods (as delicious as they are) like bagels, muffins, and croissants.

Lately though, I have not had a lot of free time to the grocery store so I have been eating some kind of breakfast sandwich (some combination of sausage, egg, cheese, and a bagel/croissant/English muffin) from my office complex's cafeteria or nearby restaurant. The cost and lack of variety associated with this are also things I would like to avoid.

Ideally, I'd like meat but I do not want to spend the time in the morning in my kitchen to prepare and cook things. I prefer to leave early in the morning to get to work to avoid the traffic. In terms of equipment I have a stove, microwave, and toaster at home. At work I have access to a toaster, a hot plate with a small pot, microwave, and hot filtered water (from the coffee machine). There are some markets close to work that open just as I get in to work so I am not opposed to driving the extra distance in the morning.

What are suggestions of foods I can buy or minimally prepare that will keep me full for a longer time?

Comment: (hard-)Boiled eggs? I usually prepare a dozen at a time and then eat them for 3 or 4 days.

Comment: Note that "whole grain" cereals are absolutely packed with carbohydrate molecules.  There is utterly no difference whatsoever etween the C-H-O (carbon, hydrogen, oxygen) molecules in "whole grain cereals" as in normal white table sugar.  It's just a CHO molecule.  There is no difference between one CHO molecule and another CHO molecule.

Comment: Cottage Cheese!

Comment: I was going to suggest yogurt, but if you don't tolerate milk, then probably yogurt won't work for you either.

Comment: I'm actually fine with yogurt and cheese, but plain cow's milk does not sit well with me. Small amounts are okay, but large glasses aren't.

Comment: Something with Chicken or Turkey would give you the cheapest and highest protein, if you can bare to eat chicken for breakfast.

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakfast?) might help you find the breakfast you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not just protein that will keep you full for longer but also fat and fibre (vegetables/whole grains). Which is why the best breakfast I find has some combination of eggs and veggies. I would strongly recommend against eating some kind of breakfast sandwich from a restaurant/cafeteria although a homemade sandwich is great. I also recommend staying away from cereals since they aren't satiating and offer a poor macro split.

Here are some balanced breakfast ideas:

- Eggs and veggies: Can be scrambled, boiled, omelette, sunny side up or however you prefer. The veggies can be raw or just cooked with the eggs. Obviously this will involve cooking in the morning -unless you eat precook boiled eggs the night before. Eggs are very nutritious and filling, while at the same time offering a [good balance of fat/protein.](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/dairy-and-egg-products/111/2)
- Deli Meat: Not only it's convenient and quick it's very versatile. You can make sandwiches/wrap with it. Introduce it in a salad. Or simply add it to your egg dish to [increase the protein ratio](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/sausages-and-luncheon-meats/1493/2). Most deli meats are fine but I prefer fresh cuts from the deli counter such as pastrami/turkey or chicken breast. You can also make your own seasoning and roasting a turkey breast or cut of beef and slicing it to make sandwiches.
- [Plain Greek yogurt](http://www.fageusa.com/products/fage-total-2-percent/#): Very high in protein and requires no cooking. You can make savory or sweet dishes with it. One option is to use it in a [labneh style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strained_yogurt#Middle_East) sandwich with olive oil and tomatoes ([Zaata'r](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Za%27atar) optional). You can also eat it with oatmeal and eggs. For a sweeter dish you add chopped fruit like bananas, apples, pears or berries. It also goes great with fruits and [muesli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muesli). You can also eat nuts/nut butters to increase the fat content.

In the end you really aren't going to find the perfect breakfast, that is nutritionally balanced and effort free. It's going to take some sacrifices by getting up earlier/cooking or just managing your time better. But that's the price you pay for having a healthier life.

Answer (score 6):

Tinned tuna, mackeral and sardines.  Not typically seen as a breakfast dish, but they are healthy and filling. Have protein and omega oils.

Very convenient, just open and go. Depending where you are they often come with a range of different sauces.

Do not eat at your desk at work.

Comment: +1 Chopsticks and tinned fish should be kept as an emergency meal. :)

Answer (score 5):

- Add powdered protein (whey, soy, whatever your preference) to your drink (almond milk is fine).
- Crack a few eggs in a pan and scramble them (takes <5 mins total).
- High protein cereal. Several types exist including one by Kashi
- More whole grains- Oatmeal works well for example.
- Don't add sugar to your meal or drink as sugar is an appetite stimulant

Answer (score 2):

You're eating too much grains and sugar. The carbs from the wheat and almond milk you eat make you crave early. They cause an early sugar boost that doesn't take long to be absorbes by your body. This leads to a sugar crash. This is when you why you get hungry again before luchtime...

Solution:

Try adding more healthy fats and protein to your meals. For example:
- eggs, nuts, avocado
- For meat you could prepare some meatballs in the evening so you can microwave them in the 
  morning...
- Add some full fat cream in your coffee
- Add some vegetables to your breakfast
- Drink some morning soup with your breakfast that you prepared the evening before
- loose the grains, wheat and sugar

Do this and you won't be hungry before lunchtime. Trust me.
For healthy recipes take a look at these wonderful sites:

http://fastpaleo.com/all-recipes/

http://nuttykitchen.com/category/paleo/

http://purelyprimal.com/category/recipes/breakfast/

Have a great breakfast!

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend a few cheap & low prep meals for you:

- 2 bean burritos & [100 calorie guacamole packs](http://eatwholly.com/products/wholly-guacamole/snack-pack.html) (18g protein) - The guac changes these from a $1 meal into a $3 meal. You could also add cheese or salsa to really pep it up.
- [Jimmy Deans D-Lites](http://jimmydean.com/products/DLights/DLights-Sandwiches/) (18g protein) - Since you're already into sandwiches, these should be better for you.
- Hard-boiled eggs (13g protein) - Try them with Tabasco Sauce!
- [0% Fat Greek Yogurt](http://www.chobani.com/products/c/nonfat) (16g protein) - I know you said milk upset your stomach, but usually people eat yogurt to help an "upset" digestive system, so I put it on there for a try.

All this stuff can be made with just a microwave.  If you want to feel "full" eat one of the things on the above list and also eat either a banana or oatmeal.  Either of those two should help make you feel really "full" and keep you well past lunch.

Answer (score 0):

A search for "crockpot breakfast" or "slow cooker breakfast" will turn up wonder results. You can do the prep at night, start the cooker, and have to do nothing in the morning but eat. The only downside is many of the recipes can't be scaled down below two servings. So you'll need to find a friend to eat the other half. On the plus side, even if you waste half the meal, they're still cheaper than the cost of most fast food breakfasts and healthier too.